# display available rooms and booked rooms in each day in fullcalander

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, fullcalendar

i trying to create hotel room booking system using laravel and fullcalander. [image]

i am currently displaying all rooms in the hotel using one color and booked rooms in another color.
i recieved those data using 2 json objects. i need to know is how to display only available rooms and booked rooms insted display all rooms and booked rooms. (this is my first project in laravel)

this is controller

```
 $booked_rooms = array();
    $bookings = Booking::all();
   
    
    foreach($bookings as $booking){

       $booked_rooms[]=[

       'title'=>$booking->room_number,
       'start'=>$booking->checkin_date,
       'end'=>$booking->checkout_date
       

       ];

    }

   
    $available_rooms = array();
    $rooms = tbl_room::all();
    foreach($rooms as $room){

        $available_rooms[]=[

        'title'=>$room->room_number,
        'start'=>'2022-01-01',
        'end'=>'2023-06-16'
       
        
        ];
     }

    return view('calander.view_calander',['booked_rooms'=>$booked_rooms],['available_rooms'=>$available_rooms]);
```

this is my script

```
<script>
     var available_rooms  = @json($available_rooms);
     var booked_rooms  = @json($booked_rooms);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calander');

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

eventSources: [
{"events":booked_rooms,
 "color":"green"   
},
{
 "events":available_rooms,
 "color":"brown"
}
```

],
});

```
calendar.render();
```

});

Comment: Really this is a SQL question about finding overlapping time periods. It has nothing much to do with laravel, and nothing at all to do with Javascript, json or fullCalendar. It's a common enough requirement with booking and reservation systems, so someone will have solved it before and outlined solutions you can apply to your scenario.

Comment: i tried but havent find solution. can you type query that how to find available rooms based on booked rooms. i will update quesion with database

Comment: Show what you've tried too, based on your research, and explain what went wrong. then we have a starting point. Otherwise I'll just be repeating your research...I don't know such a query from memory.